# Excel content add-in on macOS: dialog box disappears

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

we are developing an add-in for Excel and it uses a DialogAPI 1.2
When the dialog is open and user clicks somewhere else in excel, the dialog disappears alltogether (is hidden "behind" the main window), so the user is completely lost in space.
Is there a way to bring the dialog back to top or prevent it from disappearing?
Or some workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Office.js dialog is nonmodal, so this is expected behavior. But a modal option is a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

You don't say what you're using the dialog for, but in most cases a workaround is to put the user interaction that you now have in the dialog into a task pane. It could be a tab within the task pane or an iFrame that appears, possibly even a floating iFrame.